# How to add Company Bitbucket Repository to Jira?

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, integration

I would love to use the 'smart commit' feature (as explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-smart-commits-in-bitbucket-server-802599018.html)), connecting BitBucket to Jira and adding a comment (or even resolving the ticket) when I commit and push something to git.

I connected my user from Jira to BitBucket (and vice versa, as explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/connect-bitbucket-cloud-to-jira-cloud-applications-814190686.html))

**Now I would like to add my repositories, but I can't seem to find any (In Jira settings > Applications > DVCS accounts > Add repository).**

The repositories I am talking about all belong to my company (and not directly to my user).

Is there any way of how I can still get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was rather simple.
The owner of the team (i.e. company) has to login and establish the connection between Jira and Bitbucket. After that it works like a charm!